# How prove this combinatoric ? simply

Tags: binomial-coefficients

I got stuck at the computation of the sum . the problem is K .
how to simply this combinatoric ?
Is this problem sorted out by directly substituting the k value? In general, the number of picks (k) changes, but in this case it is constant.(n)
What does this mean?
$$

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: Please do not use pictures for critical portions of your post. Pictures may not be legible, cannot be searched and are not view-able to some, such as those who use screen readers. – For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 1):

As OP has now edited to present some of their ideas, here is a very simple proof.
We find

$$\sum_{k=0}^n k {2n-k\choose n} = \sum_{k=0}^n k {2n-k\choose n-k}
= [z^n] (1+z)^{2n} \sum_{k=0}^n k z^k (1+z)^{-k}.$$

Here the coefficient extractor enforces the upper range of the sum and we have

$$[z^n] (1+z)^{2n} \sum_{k\ge 0} k z^k (1+z)^{-k}
= [z^n] (1+z)^{2n} \frac{z/(1+z)}{(1-z/(1+z))^2}
\\ = [z^n] (1+t)^{2n} z (1+z) = [z^{n-1}] (1+z)^{2n+1}
= {2n+1\choose n-1}.$$